# save_screenshot cannot work properly in for loop

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

```
medium_timeout = Data.medium_timeout

#click multiple buttons
#i = 0
for steps in buttonData:
    if steps == "wait":
        time.sleep(2)
    elif steps == "back":
        driver.back()
    else:
        try:
            #wait for element to show up
            WebDriverWait(driver, medium_timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, steps)))
            WebDriverWait(driver, medium_timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, steps)))

            #crashpicturename = "before" + "error" + str(i) + ".png"
            #driver.save_screenshot(crashpicturename)
        except TimeoutException:
            logging.debug(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " TimeoutException: Unable to locate " + steps)
            return driver
        #Input some data where necessary
        if steps == "//input[@id = 'fulfill']":
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id= 'orderItemsContainer']//input").send_keys(str(randint(10000, 99999)))
        logging.debug(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " Clicking on " + steps)
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(steps).click()
            logging.debug(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " after Clicking on " + steps)

            crashpicturename = "after" + "error" + str(i) + ".png"
            driver.save_screenshot(crashpicturename)
            i += 1

        except Exception as e:
            logging.debug(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + format(e))
            time.sleep(10)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath(steps).click()


return driver
```

During this testing, I plan to click "user" first, then click "edit", then click"change email" to test these steps work normally, at the same time, save screenshots after every step. But it seems save_screenshot for PhantomJS can not work normally. For example, the screenshot after clicking "user" has the same screenshot after clicking "change email". IT is messy.